# How to limit printing contents of ASCII file to once while using recursion?

Tags: c, dos, fat, floppy

Trying to read the parent directory from a FAT12 floppy disk. I can currently read and print the contents of the files in the parent directories and traverse into the subdirectories and print their content if they are and ASCII file. The problem is that when reading files from subdirectories that are ASCII their contents print twice. I want to see how to counter this problem. Do I have to use a different structure of recursion? Here is the function right now:

```
void readDirectory(int fd, off_t dir_offset) {
    // Seek to the directory table
    lseek(fd, dir_offset, SEEK_SET);
    uint16_t cluster_number;

    char entry[DIR_ENTRY_SIZE];
    ssize_t bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = read(fd, entry, DIR_ENTRY_SIZE)) == DIR_ENTRY_SIZE) {
        // Check if the entry is not empty and not a volume label
        if (entry[0] != 0x00 && entry[0] != 0x2E && entry[11] != 0x0F) {
            // Extract filename
            char filename[MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH + 1];
            strncpy(filename, entry, MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH);
            filename[MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH] = '\0';

            // Check if the entry is marked as deleted
            if ((unsigned char)entry[0] == 0xE5) {
                printf("\nDeleted File: %s\n", filename);
            } else {
                // Print filename and attributes
                if (entry[11] & 0x10) {  // Check if it's a directory
                    printf("\nDirectory: %s\n", filename);                    
                        // Extract starting cluster for subdirectory
                        cluster_number = *((uint16_t *)&entry[26]);
                        // Calculate offset for subdirectory based on cluster number
                        off_t sub_dir_offset = calculateClusterOffset(cluster_number);
                        // Read contents of subdirectory recursively
                        readDirectory(fd, sub_dir_offset);
                } else {
                    printf("\nFilename: %s\n", filename);
                    printf("Attributes: 0x%02X\n", entry[11]);
                    printf("Size: %hu\n", *((uint16_t *)&entry[28]));
                    printf("Start Cluster: %u\n", *((uint16_t *)&entry[26]));
                    cluster_number = *((uint16_t *)&entry[26]);
                    // File is an ASCII file, print its contents
                    off_t file_offset = calculateClusterOffset(cluster_number);
                    uint16_t file_size = *((uint16_t *)&entry[28]);
                    printf("ASCII contents:\n");
                    printFileContents(fd, file_offset, file_size, cluster_number);
                }
            }
        } else if (entry[0] == 0x00) {
            // End of directory marker
            break;
        }
        
        // Update the file offset to point to the next directory entry
        dir_offset += DIR_ENTRY_SIZE;
        lseek(fd, dir_offset, SEEK_SET);
    }

    if (bytesRead == -1) {
        perror("Error reading directory entry");
    }
}
```

I have all of the correct output it's just that every file from a subdirectory is printed twice. Also would like to just understand why this is happening so I can avoid it in the future.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to add details and findings from debugging. You might want to read ["How to debug small programs"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for this. It is well possible that you see your error during this. If you still have an issue, please describe it in detail and extend your source to a [mre].